# Pyspark not able to write to apache ignite

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, ignite

Python version: **3.10.4**
PySpark version: **3.3.0**

I'm trying to run the following code but getting NoSuchMethodError on line 5 while trying to write to ignite from pyspark dataframe. I looked up on stackoverflow few people had same problem with scala spark there they said its because of version mismatch in but here I checked out spark 3.3.0 works fine with python 3.8+

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.config("spark.ssl.enabled",True).appName("test").getOrCreate()
url = "jdbc:xxx://xx.xxx.xx.xxx:xxxx/dbxx"
configFile = os.environ['IGNITE_HOME'] + "/config/default-config.xml"
leads = spark.read.jdbc(url=url,table="public.xxx", properties={"user": "xxx"})
leads.write.format("ignite").option("table","xxx").option("primaryKeyFields","id").option("config",configFile).save()
```

I'm trying to write dataframe to ignite but I get following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py", line 966, in save
    self._jwrite.save()
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.5-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1321, in __call__
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 190, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.5-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 326, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o53.save.
: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.Predef$.refArrayOps([Ljava/lang/Object;)Lscala/collection/mutable/ArrayOps;
        at org.apache.ignite.spark.impl.QueryHelper$.ensureCreateTableOptions(QueryHelper.scala:84)
        at org.apache.ignite.spark.impl.IgniteRelationProvider.createRelation(IgniteRelationProvider.scala:154)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.run(SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.scala:45)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:75)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:73)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.executeCollect(commands.scala:84)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1.$anonfun$applyOrElse$1(QueryExecution.scala:98)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$6(SQLExecution.scala:109)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:169)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1(SQLExecution.scala:95)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:779)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:64)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1.applyOrElse(QueryExecution.scala:98)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1.applyOrElse(QueryExecution.scala:94)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$transformDownWithPruning$1(TreeNode.scala:584)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:176)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDownWithPruning(TreeNode.scala:584)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$logical$AnalysisHelper$$super$transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:30)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDownWithPruning(AnalysisHelper.scala:267)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDownWithPruning$(AnalysisHelper.scala:263)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:30)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:30)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:560)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.eagerlyExecuteCommands(QueryExecution.scala:94)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.commandExecuted$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:81)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.commandExecuted(QueryExecution.scala:79)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.assertCommandExecuted(QueryExecution.scala:116)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:860)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveToV1Source(DataFrameWriter.scala:390)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveInternal(DataFrameWriter.scala:363)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:247)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
        at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
        at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
        at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
        at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
        at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ignite does not currently directly support Spark 3.x. You might be able to use the Spark JDBC/ODBC driver.

Comment: Thanks, That worked. but now I'm getting No Primary key Defined error. seems like I have to create a table before hand in ignite. is there a other way around?

Comment: I tried creating table in ignite with primary key but it doesn't let me append or overwrite?

Comment: IIRC, when you use overwrite, it drops and re-creates the table. The last time I checked, append worked. I don't know Spark well, so I don't know if you can specify the primary key or CREATE TABLE command some other way.

Comment: append worked fine. I just had make sure that table exist beforehand.